# "WSMan Initialization failed with error code: -2144108171" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, model-view-controller, powershell-2.0

I have MVC web app controller to connect exchange server powershell with the following codes:

```
  enter connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get   ("WSManConnectionInfo").ToString()), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",  newCred);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
string rspace = "space is OK";
        try
        {
            //--create remote runspace
            runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
        } catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            rspace = ex2.Message.ToString();
        }
        ViewBag.rspace = rspace; //show the above error message on client side view
```

The above codes works fine from my local machine, but I got the above error after publishing to production server, please note I can see the "Microsoft.Management.Infrustructure.dll" is existed on the bin folder of production server.

Please advise if how to fix this error, much appreciated,

Edit: I even tried to add these 3 lines codes, but same error;

connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;

connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;

connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 4;code here

Edit: the  System.Management.Automation.dll is also added in the Reference folder

Comment: Does anybody have any solutions? much appreciated for any help,

Comment: Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem has been resolved, I think it was caused by the System.Management.Automation installation, this is what I did:

1.First make sure the System.Management.Automation.dll is added in the References folder from  C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll , this dll file was there, but it still causesthe error,

2.Go to Manage Nuget package and install System.Management.Automation from there, although they have the same name, but I think this file is different than the System.Management.Automation.dll added on the first step.  but after installing this file, thenthe problem is gone. there is nothing changes for the C# codes,